# How to manually boot with grub or: how to boot a 32bit Linux OS on a 32bit only UEFI firmware computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, bootloader

I want to install a 32bit Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) on my Intel Atom Bay Trail tablet, but I fail to get it to boot. The device's firmware only supports 32bit bootloaders. There are guides that somewhat work, if I use a 64bit OS, like this one: https://github.com/jfwells/linux-asus-t100ta/tree/master/boot
It allows me to get into the ubuntu network installer, where my tablet's internal storage isn't recognized for partitioning. Even if it did work, it would be highly suboptimal, considering that the device only has 1GB of RAM and a 64bit would have a much higher idle memory usage.
So my current goal is to at least get into the installer with a 32bit OS. If I use a bootia32.efi file on a 32bit Ubuntu 14.10 install flash drive I can get into grub, but I have to manually enter the boot commands. Can anyone help me with that?

[image: I can select the flash drive]

[image: What next?]

Yes, I am wearing an Ubuntu shirt. Coincidence, I swear.

Comment: Your computer doesn't even have the capability of running a 64-bit operating system because it only supports 32-bit EFI drivers.  Have you tried to simple install a 32-bit version of Ubuntu to your disk?

Comment: Of course the device can run a 64bit OS, I have already been in the 64bit installer and used some devices and bash. If you read the question I am right now trying to install the 32bit version.

64bit OS + 32 bit bootloader + 32 bit UEFI allows me to get into the installer, but I want to do the same with a 32bit OS.

Comment: You can't boot a a 64-bit boot loader on a 32-bit UEFI machine they have to be the same unless you want to use compatability mode

Comment: You can try some distros with light desktop environment like Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Some can be found [here](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/780781-6-excellent-lightweight-linux-distros-for-x86-and-arm). 64-bit distros aren't really much more memory consuming, because only pointers are double. If you want to lower memory usage even more, use a [distro with x32 ABI](http://lwn.net/Articles/548838/)

Comment: [Ubuntu on 32-bit UEFI (only) based tablet pc](http://askubuntu.com/q/775498/253474), [Linux distro with !32bit! (U)EFI support?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251705/44425), [Installing linux on an 32bit UEFI only machine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155557/44425), [Installing Ubuntu 15.04 on BayTrail tablets](https://sturmflut.github.io/linux/ubuntu/2015/01/21/installing-ubuntu-15.04-on-baytrail-tablets/), [32bit EFI with 64 bit linux OS. Can it be done?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296096/44425). http://askubuntu.com/a/715843/253474